# pdfBox generated pdf is size is larger than itext Generated pdf . is there any compression technique in pdfbox java

Tags: java, pdfbox

i have created pdf using itext library, pdf size is 1mb
but using pdfbox library with same data ,it will become 15mb .

PDFBOX is Free Library .if there is compression technique or method which will helps to compress pdf size.

Comment: Please share your PDF and tell what version you are using and what you did.

Comment: Indeed, which versions of iText with which code do you compare to which versions of PDFBox with which code? Without knowing such details we can only try shots in the dark...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.